# Docker: connection reset by peer

Tags: centos, docker

I have a physical CentOS 7 host *(A)* on my LAN (192.168.0.0/16). SElinux is disabled, and firewalld is disabled. It is the only changes I made from install defaults.

I have an other host *(B)* on that LAN; *(B)* has services like www, ssh, icmp.

At this step, I can play with *(B)* from *(A)*:

```
$ ping *(B)*
 ... success ...
$ curl google.com
 ... success ...
$ curl *(B)*
 ... success ...
$ mysql *(B)*
 ... success ...
```

Everything is running fine.

Now, I install Docker Community on *(A)*:

```
$ yum check-update
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
$ systemctl start docker
```

And now the results of such commands again on *(A)*:

```
$ ping *(B)*
 ... success ...
$ curl google.com
 ... success ...    
$ curl *(B)*
 ... Recv failure: Connection reset by peer ...
$ mysql *(B)*
 ... Connection reset by peer ...
```

So basically, once Docker is setup and active, all TCPs connections from *(A)* (the host OR a docker container) to my LAN failed. Such error are likely to be a firewall issue, because TCPs connections from *(B)* to *(A)* are still available.

However I check iptables on *(A)* for REJECT rules or policies mistakes and there is absolutely nothing. I even clean iptables entirely on *(A)*, and the problem still occur.

If all firewalls/security systems are disabled or empty of restrictives rules, and with permissives policies, I don't understand where is the problem and where I have to check on my CentOS system to solve the issue.

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the docker bridge IP may be colliding with IP's on your network. If this is a completely clean installation and there wasn't a /var/lib/docker from before, then look into adjusting the `bip` setting in the docker daemon. You'll know this is an issue if `docker network inspect bridge` shows an IP range you need, and `netstat -nr` (or `ip r`) shows the IP range used by docker0 also being used by other interfaces or as a gateway. To update the `bip` setting, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

Comment: I have both adjusting the docker bip and modify IP/Mask on all my interfaces from all my hosts to avoid collisions, and it works. Thanks !